# Converter JSON em UTF-8 no Android

Tags: php, java, android, json, array

Tenho um `JSON Array` e quando é exibido em uma `ListView` no Android, aparece com caracteres especias:

[image: Exemplo]

**<sub>JSON gerado pelo php:</sub>**

```
[{"id":"1","titulo":"X-Burg","descricao":"Hambúrguer,...","preco":"R$ 7,50","tipo":"0"},{"id":"2","titulo":"Dogão","descricao":"Salsicha,...:"R$ 7,50","tipo":"0"}...]
```

**Código `Java` resumido:**

<sub>Converter:</sub>

```
 private CardapioEntities convertCardapio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String titulo = obj.getString(TAG_TITULO);
        String descricao = obj.getString(TAG_DESCRICAO);
        String preco = obj.getString(TAG_PRECO);
        String tipo = obj.getString(TAG_TIPO);

        return new CardapioEntities(titulo, descricao, preco, tipo);
    }
```

<sub>Pegar o `JSON` e jogar na `ListView`</sub>

```
private void _getCardapio(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                CardapioEntities cardapioEntities = new CardapioEntities();
                if (convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioTipo().contains("0")) {
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioTitulo(convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioTitulo());
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioDescricao(convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioDescricao());
                    cardapioEntities.setCardapioPreco(convertCardapio(json.getJSONObject(i)).getCardapioPreco());
                    listaLanches.add(cardapioEntities);
                } 
            }
            final ListView lvLanches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLanches);
            lvLanches.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listaLanches));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*Dicas e exemplos de melhorias são sempre bem vindas.*

Comment: veja isso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324956/android-convert-json-to-uft-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi, o problema estava aqui:

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

Adicionei o `iso-8859-1` e funcinou!

> Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14949076/3456409

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de utilizar o JSONObject e pegar dado por dado, utilize a biblioteca GSON referenciando seu objeto que recebera todos os dados, lembrando que seu objeto( CardapioEntities ) deverá ter seus atributos com o mesmo nome que vem do json.

Por exemplo voce poderia criar um objeto que contém uma lista de cardapio.

```
public class ListaCardapioEntities {

  private List<CardapioEntities> cardapioEntitiesList;

  //construtor
  //get set
```

}

```
 private ListaCardapioEntities convertCardapio(String json) throws JSONException {
     Gson gson = new Gson();
    ListaCardapioEntities listaCardapioEntities = gson.fromJson( json, ListaCardapioEntities.class );

    return listaCardapioEntities;
}
```

E no seu json coloque ele assim

```
{ "cardapioEntitiesList" : [{"id":"1","titulo":"X-Burg","descricao":"Hambúrguer,...","preco":"R$ 7,50","tipo":"0"},{"id":"2","titulo":"Dogão","descricao":"Salsicha,...:"R$ 7,50","tipo":"0"}]}
```

E sobre o charSet está UTF-8 ? Se não então experimente colocá-lo.

```
String resposta = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```